# Make zsh complete arguments from a file

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

`zsh` is great but its completion system is very diverse. And the documentation lacks good examples. Is there a template for completing for a specific application. The completion would get its match data from a file, separated by newlines?

I tried modifying an older example of mine that takes match data "live":

```
~ % cat .zsh/completers/_jazzup 
#compdef jazz_up
_arguments "2: :(`mpc lsplaylists|sed -e 's# #\\\\ #g'`)"
```

I could supply `cat my_file` there instead of `mpc` invocation and so on but would there be a more elegant way to do this simple task? And that completion there is placement-specific: can you provide an example where zsh would attempt to complete at any point after the program name is recognized?

The match data will have whitespaces and so on, the completion should escape the WS. Example of that:

```
Foo bar
Barbaric
Get it (42)
```

Now if that completion would be configured for a command `Say`, we should get this kind of behaviour out of `zsh`:

```
$ Say Fo<TAB>
$ Say Foo\ bar
$ Say Ge<TAB>
$ Say Get\ it\ \(42\)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simple completion needs are better addressed with `_describe`, it pairs an array holding completion options and a description for them (you can use multiple array/description pairs, check the manual).

(`_arguments` is great but too complex.)

[...]

First create a file

```
echo "foo\nbar\nbaz\nwith spac e s\noh:noes\noh\:yes" >! ~/simple-complete
```

Then create a file `_simple` somewhere in your `$fpath`:

```
#compdef simple

# you may wish to modify the expansion options here
# PS: 'f' is the flag making one entry per line
cmds=( ${(uf)"$(< ~/simple-complete)"} ) 

# main advantage here is that it is easy to understand, see alternative below
_describe 'a description of the completion options' cmds

# this is the equivalent _arguments command... too complex for what it does
## _arguments '*:foo:(${cmds})'
```

then

```
function simple() { echo $* }
autoload _simple # do not forget BEFORE the next cmd! 
compdef _simple simple # binds the completion function to a command

simple [TAB]
```

it works. Just make sure the completion file `_simple` is placed somewhere in your `fpath`.

Notice that `:` in the option list is supposed to be used for separating an option from their (individual) description (`oh:noes`). So that won't work with `_describe` unless you quote it (`oh\:yes`). The commented out `_arguments` example will not use the `:` as a separator.

Comment: Fantastic. I'll award some bounty if you can open a bit about references and the details but this serves as the perfect example I was looking for.

Comment: Thank you, so much. This is by far the most concise walkthrough I've found for zsh completion. It deserves far more upvotes than it's received.

Comment: Where can I get infos about the `uf` flags

Comment: Does not work if you forget to autload. AFter autoloading it works.[See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236891/72988)

Comment: The docs say that you can do own `compdefs` without a file like `_simple`. However, I did not find out how. Poor docs..

Comment: In case anyone likes to see `_describe` without a `file`: `cmds=('--stat:Zeige Dateinamen' '-p: Zeige Inhalte' '--graph:Zeige foo')
_describe 'Git Log P.' cmds`

Answer (score 2):

Without changing anything further in `.zshrc` (I already have `autoload -Uz compinit
compinit`) I added the following as `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_drush`

```
#compdef drush
_arguments "1: :($(/usr/local/bin/aliases-drush.php))"
```

Where `/usr/local/bin/aliases-drush.php` just prints a list of strings, each string being a potential first argument for the command drush. You could use `($(< filename))` to complete from `filename`.

I based this on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458850/9452 -- it's surprising how simple this is at the end of the day.