# bad set of key/value pairs for associative array for custom completion

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I am trying to follow [Make zsh complete arguments from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17318913/308851) but with a command. Shouldn't matter much.

In `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_foo` I have

```
#compdef foo
aliases=($(a complicated command here printing everything twice))
_describe aliases aliases
```

The command when ran alone prints this:

```
foo foo bar bar this this that that
```

This seems to create an associative array just fine. When I add `echo ${(kv)aliases}` before the `_describe aliases aliases` command and run `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_foo` I am getting

```
foo foo bar bar this this that that
```

And when I just do `${(k)aliases}` then

```
foo bar this that
```

I do not really a description so this would work for me. But, it doesn't work for zsh.

I added

```
function foo() { echo $* }
autoload _foo
compdef _foo foo
```

to `~/.zshrc` and after `. ~/.zshrc` when I type `foo [tab]` I get `_foo:2: bad set of key/value pairs for associative array`. I tried changing the command to only print everything once. Same results. I tried changing the command to print `"foo:x "` for every foo. Same results. So what about should my program produce for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

`aliases` already exists as an associative array containing all your shell aliases. Call the variable something else.

It may alias help to declare your variable local, for a normal array:

```
local -a compl_aliases
```

The bad set of key/value pairs usually indicates that you have an odd number of elements when doing an associative array assignment. There needs to be an even number with a value for each key.

Comment: Oh. That's a bummer. I will leave this up now; I posted a diffrent working solution to the linked parent question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51550248/308851